# How to get country dialling code using country code or country name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, geoip

I want to get Country dialling code like `+91(India)` through Country Name (India) OtherWise Country Code (IN).

Example through I was getting country name and country code,

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(result) {
  alert(result.country_code); 
  alert(result.country_name);    
});
```

Comment: this api does not return country dialing code, for that there may be a separate api.Please share that api

Comment: @brk i know this url http://freegeoip.net/json/ does not return dialing code so my question is how to get dialing code.

Comment: You'd have to use something like => http://country.io/phone.json

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone still looking for the answer. You can use library called `libphonenumber-js`

```js
import { getCountryCallingCode } from "libphonenumber-js";

const countryIsoCode = "IN";
const regionNames = new Intl.DisplayNames(["en"], { type: "region" });
const countryCode = getCountryCallingCode(countryIsoCode);
const countryDialingCode = `+${countryCode}(${regionNames.of(countryIsoCode)})`;


console.log(countryDialingCode)
//  +91(India)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this i way too late but it might help someone at some point

[RestCountries](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/India?fullText=true)